# jQuery click event is not working on an overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

http://lunapark.waapps.net/en/ please go to "News" and click on first post image. On click event is calling a gallery script with jQuery ajax method. Later on click event must be open a new overlay on previous overlay. Not open but when you close the first overlay -so News' overlay- it turn on and you can see the gallery. This problem is ocurring on just Safari browser. How can I fix this? Any idea please. Already now thanks.

This script is running gallery's overlay

```
$('div.multiple_img a[href$="jpg"], div.single_img a[href$="png"]').click(function(){
    var post_id = $(this).parents().find(".post-content").next().val();
    $.get(URL+'/get_gallery.php?post_id='+post_id, function(data){
        var sw = $("#image_wrapper_2");
        sw.html(data);
        $("body").addClass("on2");
        $("#overlay2 #page_bg").css("background-color",ww.find(">div").attr("data-bgcolor"));

        if(!($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == '8.0') && !works.isApple()) 
            $("#overlay2").mCustomScrollbar("vertical",400,"easeOutCirc",1,"auto","yes","yes",15);

        works.scrollTo(400, $("#overlay2"), 0);
    });
    return false;

});
```

This script is running first overlay

```
loadPage : function (url){
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function(data){
        var pw = $("#page_wrapper");
        pw.html(data);
        $("#page_bg").css("background-color",pw.find(">div").attr("data-bgcolor"));
        $("body").addClass("on");

        if(!($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == '8.0') && !works.isApple()) 
            $("#overlay").mCustomScrollbar("vertical",400,"easeOutCirc",1,"auto","yes","yes",15);

        $(".loader").removeClass("on");
        $("#main-nav a").removeClass("show_loader");
        works.scrollTo(400, $("#overlay"), 0);
```

first script is running in loadPage object's ajax method

Comment: please add some script or markup if you expect people to giva an answer to your question

Comment: looks better..  BTW I like the style of that page..

Comment: I have to say it's a really cool website. Good job! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this issue caused by css visibility. When I change my css properties from

```
#overlay2{
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    opacity:.94;
    z-index: 60;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-in .1s;
    -moz-transition:all .3s ease-in .1s;
    -ms-transition:all .3s ease-in .1s;
    -o-transition:all .3s ease-in .1s;
    transition:all .3s ease-in .1s;
}

body.on2  #overlay2{
    visibility:visible !important;
    opacity:1;
}
```

to

```
display: none; for #overlay
display: block; for body.on2  #overlay2
```

is working for Safari but at the same time gallery does not work on opened second overlay.